# Assets are not shown in dev environment

Tags: php, css, symfony, assetic

I have this in the HEAD block:

```
    {% stylesheets filter='yui_css' output='css/base.css'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/css/ui/south-street/jquery-ui.css'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/css/base.css'
             filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}         

    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}

    {% javascripts filter='yui_js' output='js/base.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

when I load app_dev.php page, all assets are not shown. when I see in firebug, this kind of assets are being trying to load:

http://server/app_dev.php/css/base_jquery-ui_1.css

in prod environment there is no problem. When I deployed and published assets, this CSS was copied into web/css folder :

http://server/app_dev.php/css/base.css

As you see in twig template, I have defined the output parameter. That is why the css has this name.

How can I solve this in dev environment?

This is symfony 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets aren’t dumped automatically. You must trigger the generation through the console.

To have them dumped once, run

```
app/console assetic:dump --force
```

You can also run a background task which periodically scans your assets for changes and creates new dumps after modifications.

As you are still on SF 2.3, the command for this background task is

```
app/console assetic:dump --watch --force
```

Note that SF 2.3 is no longer maintained. You should upgrade to at least SF 2.7 or 2.8 which are the [currently maintained long-term support versions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule).

In newer versions of Assetic, bundled with newer SF versions, the `watch` command is

```
app/console assetic:watch --force
```

Comment: I did it, but even when assets were correctly generated, they were not loaded. To solve this, I needed to change dev configuration to not use controller before the asset path. Why is this? isn't it supposed the controller to point correctly to the assets?

Comment: Have you checked that the `{{ asset_url }}` generated by assetic is correct? If not, how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: When "use controller" setting is true, generated URL include app_dev.php before the actual asset path.  I have used older versions of symfony, and they did not have these problems. I remember that it was not necessary to deploy assets in web folder, because the controller task is supposed to be precisely that, to send the asset content to the browser at development time without the need to actual copy the assets to web folder.  At least, that was the behaviour before, and if this does not work the same way now., what is the goal of the "use controller" setting? I work with symfony since 1.4.

Comment: SF 1.x is *completely* different from 2.x. They only share the name, almost all of the concepts are different. I'm not sure about how 2.3 handles assets, because I've upgraded to later versions long ago. But you may try removing the `use_controller` setting and see what it does. Or fiddle around with the other asset-related config values. By the way, is the `web` folder your document root? If not, it should be.

Comment: Yes.. as I told, that was finally the solution. First I needed to deploy de assets to web folder.... then, set to false "use controller" setting. However, I wonder what is the goal of that option if controller is not capable to send assets to browser on the fly as previous versions does

Comment: Apparently not. I guess this is because Assetic and Twig are loosely coupled to Symfony. They would have to listen to some kind of event in order to know. Although this would not be too hard to implement, it would be very costly to check/regenerate assets on each request – you would have to wait one or more seconds before having the page document rendered. I think it’s more efficient to have it in the background task.